# `numpy` histogram and digitize for binning

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

### General Setup

Oftentimes in categorical or data analysis, I want to "lump" categories together. For instance, if users are given the ability to state their preference between values 1 - 6, I might want to lump together `[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]`.

It would appear to me that `numpy.digitize()` is a natural extension of `numpy.histogram()` that should give me the ability to perform what I mentioned above.

For example, let's create a random array of with an even number of integers in it:

```
In [337]: arr = numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=6, size=100)
In [340]: numpy.unique(arr)
Out[340]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`numpy.historgram(bins=3)` performs as expected, creating the following bins, and appropriate mapping.

```
In [338]: freq, bins = numpy.histogram(arr, bins=3)
In [339]: print(bins)

Out[339]:
array([ 0.        ,  1.66666667,  3.33333333,  5.      ]))
```

It should be noted that [according the `numpy.histogram()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), the intervals are

This maps as expected, where, from the docs:

> **Notes**
>
> All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open.  In other words,
>   if `bins` is::
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> then the first bin is `[1, 2)` (including 1, but excluding 2) and
>   the second `[2, 3)`.  The last bin, however, is `[3, 4]`, which
>   *includes* 4.

- `[0, 1]` ==> 1
- `[2, 3]` ==> 2
- `[4, 5]` ==> 3

### The "Gotcha" from `numpy.digitize()`

If we're following the same logic that `numpy.histogram` uses to construct its bins, then
the function `numpy.digitize(arr, bins=bins)` should seamlessly get us to the desired result,
and doing so using the same logic that was used to create the bins. **However,** running the 
following code produces a curious result:

```
In [340]: bind_arr = numpy.digitize(
                      arr, bins=bins)
In [341]: print(numpy.unique(bind_arr))
Out[347]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

What has happened is that `numpy.digitize` assumes that `bin[i - 1] <= x < bin[i]`, meaning that
the `5.` that was included in the `bin` construction is now **excluded** (and given its own bin)

The simple hack that I've used has been:

```
In [348]: tol = .0001
In [349]: bins[-1] += tol
```

Now the `numpy.digitize()` function works as expected, and the below function provides the expected result:

```
In [358]: bind_arr2 = numpy.digitize(arr, bins=bins)
In [359]: print(numpy.unique(bind_arr2))
Out[359]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

**My Question:** Is there a straightforward way to perform the (commonplace) operations I listed above without
incrementing the final bin? This seems like inconsistent logic, no? Lastly, is this type of logic valid enough (in people's opinion) that I should make a pull request to add the functionality to `numpy.digitize()`?

Comment: I can't find the numpy function called bins? Did you mean histogram?

Comment: Made the fix, good catch @UpSampler, thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's worth a pull request.  They already have a way to control the whether the right or the left edge is included with the `right` keyword, but there is no way to exclude both.

Comment: @zaq, good find, the `fmin` solution presented there is the type of solve I was looking for.